# How to load user control to a panel by button click in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I wanted to load a user control to a panel with a button, but when I tried this code it shows nothing. I wonder if there is a solution for my problem because I've already tried many solutions from internet but nothing worked.

this is my code :

on user cotrol

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static UserControl1 _instance;
    public static UserControl1 Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new UserControl1();
            return _instance;
        }
    }
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

on winform by button click

```
private void b1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!panel5.Controls.Contains(UserControl1.Instance))
        {
            panel5.Controls.Add(UserControl1.Instance);
            UserControl1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
            UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
    }
```

main form

[image]

user control

[image]

Thanks for your concern.

Comment: you want user control to be singleton ?

Comment: sorry i don't understand

Comment: i want to show the user control to the form by clicking the dashboard button

Comment: brother your code is working fine. make sure your panel is properly placed and visible on your form

Comment: It's not good idea to add a static instance of a UserControl to a form.

Comment: @MiyukiOuka and also, make sure you panel has enough space (area) to show you user control properly. make a temporary change.. change back color of your usercontrol.. and then click. if you can see some part of your user control.

Comment: @Amit I've already changed the color on both user control or winform but it still not show anything

Comment: @RezaAghaei do you have a soulution?

Comment: are you able to see even panel on your form or not?

Comment: @Amit only the panel when run the program? no i dont

Comment: @Amit alright now i know the problem

Comment: see this maybe what your problem is.. (if you have not tried it yet) change color of panel and run program. still  you are not able to see it.. that means.. your problem is you cannot see panel (not you can't see control)

Comment: Yes that because I set the border style to none so I'm not being able to see the panel

Comment: No, it will just disappear border, not whole panel.

Comment: @Amit thanks for the solution.

Comment: @MiyukiOuka "Thanks?" problem solved ?

Comment: @Amit yes the border was disappear,but it also didn't show the user control when i changed the border to visible the user control was shown inside the panel

Comment: @Amit yes it solved

Answer (score 1):

try this.
Hope this will help .you

```
private void set2ControlTopanel(control f) {

    try {
        p2Form = f;
        p2Form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        p2Form.Show();
        panelTop.Controls.Add(p2Form);
        p2Form.BringToFront();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        MsgBox(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you explain what does your code do and how it will help OP in his problem ? and also what is this `p2Form` ?

Comment: @Amit i think p2form is a name of the user control

Comment: Its an name of of panel on which you want to add controls

Comment: above code will dock your control of complete form to the pannel